# BFGS vs. Levenberg-Marquardt

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I know that BFGS is a general quasi-Newton method, whereas Levenberg-Marquardt (LM) is specifically for non-linear least squares (NLLS). That said, is there a big advantage of using LM instead of BFGS for NLLS problems?